# Progress bar for event with unknown duration (PySide)

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a GUI developed using PySide. I have a long operation to perform from the interface, but there is no way to predict how long the operation will be. I'd like to display something to the user to tell him: the operation is in progress, please wait. Something like an infinite progress bar, or a spinning wheel. Is there a widget for such operation in Qt? I found the QProgressDialog (and QProgressBar), but it's not appropriate since I cannot predict the amount of work to perform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer in [QProgressBar](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QProgressBar.html) documentation:

> If minimum and maximum both are set to 0, the bar shows a busy
>   indicator instead of a percentage of steps. This is useful, for
>   example, when using PySide.QtNetwork.QFtp or
>   PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager to download items when they are
>   unable to determine the size of the item being downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

If you want an infinite progress bar or spinning wheel, just have it play, then when you finish the process, stop and/or delete the bar/icon from the screen.